# Probability resulting from uncertainty when the measuring device exactly clicks?

Tags: quantum-information, probability, measurements, born-rule

### Background

Let's say I have $2$ set of eigenkets of observables of a system $|x_i \rangle $ and $|p_j \rangle$ (which do not commute). Let's say I have a non-ideal detector in the sense the experimentalists are uncertain when exactly the detector clicked but they are certain it clicks in the time interval $a$.

Consider the following setup:

One measures the observable whose eigenkets these are $|p_j \rangle$ (but you are not told the outcome). After some time $b$ you do a measurement and the outcome is $|x_0\rangle$. You try to infer by the Born rule what is the probability $P$ the original state was $p_0$. A simple calculation yields:

$$ P_{ideal}(|p_0 \rangle)= |\langle p_0 |U(b)|x_0\rangle|^2$$

where $U$ is the time evolution operator. However when you take into account you are uncertain when exactly the detector clicked (assuming uniform certainty the detector clicked between $[b,b+a)$)

$$ P_{Non-ideal}(|p_0\rangle) = \frac{\int_0^a|\langle p_0 | U( b+t)|x_0 \rangle|^2  dt}{\int_0^a dt} $$

### Question

Is the above $P_{Non-ideal}$ correct (it can be derived by multiplying the numerator and denominator by $dt$ after applying this [trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3417435/competing-ways-to-calculate-the-probability))? While this seems to be work in a Galelian world, is a relativistic version possible? My worries is the above formula is not Lorentz invariant.

Comment: If this is supposed to model experimental error in determining $t$, why not use the standard notions of error propagation instead of explicitly modelling a probability distribution for the error?

Comment: @acuriousmind I'm not aware what the 'standard notions'  are.

Comment: [Propagation of uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty)